# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden when using untangle python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, python-3.6

This is my first attempt with python, Im trying to use an external library for xml parsing for python 3.6.

I'm getting an error which doesn't seem to have anything to do with my code, and I can't figure out what the problem is from the error output

my code:

```
import untangle
x = untangle.parse(r"C:\file.xml")
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Project/Main.py", line 2, in <module>
    x = untangle.parse(r"C:\file.xml")
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\untangle.py", line 177, in parse
    parser.parse(filename)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py", line 111, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\xml\sax\xmlreader.py", line 125, in parse
    self.feed(buffer)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py", line 217, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
  File "..\Modules\pyexpat.c", line 668, in ExternalEntityRef
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\xml\sax\expatreader.py", line 413, in external_entity_ref
    "")
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\xml\sax\saxutils.py", line 364, in prepare_input_source
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(source.getSystemId())
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: Could you post some more information, like the code you use?

HTTP return code 403 means what it says: Forbidden. So you connect to the HTTP server but perhaps you need to log in first.

Comment: My entire code is just importing untangle module and calling `untangle.parse(url)`. I downloaded untangle using `pip install untangle`. What could be wrong here? I'm not trying to make any Http request from my code

Comment: You should still post a [MCVE] (along with relevant inputs). Nobody can tell you what's going wrong sight unseen, problem unreproduced.

Comment: @pvg Added all the info

Comment: This is a misfeature of many XML parsers in which they will, in their default configuration, go off resolving urls in various directives. It's been the source of a number of nasty security bugs over the years, you should just turn those particular bits of the underlying parser off if you don't want it to do that.

Comment: How can I change the configuration and turn those particular bits off? Does this require a change in the untangle's code?